# Auto Generate Row Number in listview

Tags: vb.net

I'm filling ListView data from access database. What I'm trying to do is to add auto generated row number. I use the following code for the purpose

```
Private Sub row_num()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        ListView1.Items(i).Text = i + 1.ToString
    Next
End Sub
```

the problem when i use this code the numbers replace the first column of data from database.
what i need show the row number in the first column , then show the data from the database in column 2 and 3 .

```
like this :
   num     name        phone 
   1       Rabeea      0521234567
   2       mark        0527654321


Public Sub showlistview()
    Dim cyear As String
    If ComboBox1.Text = "2014" Then
        cyear = "pay_2014"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "2015" Then
        cyear = "pay_2015"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "2016" Then
        cyear = "pay_2016"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "2017" Then
        cyear = "pay_2017"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "2018" Then
        cyear = "pay_2018"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "2019" Then
        cyear = "pay_2019"
    End If

    Dim cmonth As String

    If ComboBox2.Text = "January_1" Then
        cmonth = "jan_1"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "February_2" Then
        cmonth = "feb_2"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "March_3" Then
        cmonth = "mar_3"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "April_4" Then
        cmonth = "apr_4"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "May_5" Then
        cmonth = "may_5"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "June_6" Then
        cmonth = "jun_6"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "July_7" Then
        cmonth = "jul_7"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "August_8" Then
        cmonth = "aug_8"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "September_9" Then
        cmonth = "sep_9"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "October_10" Then
        cmonth = "oct_10"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "November_11" Then
        cmonth = "nov_11"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "December_12" Then
        cmonth = "dec_12"
    End If

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from " & cyear & " where " & cmonth & "=0", con)
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim myrow As DataRow
    For Each myrow In dt.Rows
        ListView1.Items.Add(myrow.Item(1))
        ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(2))

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, `i + 1.ToString` should be `(i + 1).ToString`.  The difference may appear unimportant but it's not.  As for the question, where exactly do you expect the row number to go?  We can't read your mind so you actually have to tell us what you want to achieve before we can tell you how to achieve it.  Also, why would you loop through the existing rows of the `ListView` instead of adding the row number when you add the rows in the first place?

Comment: you fill a perfectly good Datatable (`da.Fill(dt)`) use it as a datasource for a DataGridView (`myDGV.DataSource = dt`) and you could get rid of most of the problem.  Creating unique IDs for data is usually the job of the database.

Comment: but the data in Id in the database not in sequence :(
all what i want add sequence numbers for row , to know how many user in list view

Comment: you are not supposed to care how the DB stores it.  You put it sequence when you fetch it using ORDER BY in your SQL

Comment: ok but when i remove user 3 for example it will be
1
2
4
5

Comment: the purpose of an ID is not to count rows for you, *that* is already available in the form: `numRows = da.Fill(dt)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

problem  solved :)

```
Public Sub showlistview()
    Dim cyear As String
    If ComboBox1.Text = "2014" Then
        cyear = "pay_2014"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "2015" Then
        cyear = "pay_2015"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "2016" Then
        cyear = "pay_2016"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "2017" Then
        cyear = "pay_2017"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "2018" Then
        cyear = "pay_2018"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "2019" Then
        cyear = "pay_2019"
    End If

    Dim cmonth As String

    If ComboBox2.Text = "January_1" Then
        cmonth = "jan_1"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "February_2" Then
        cmonth = "feb_2"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "March_3" Then
        cmonth = "mar_3"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "April_4" Then
        cmonth = "apr_4"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "May_5" Then
        cmonth = "may_5"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "June_6" Then
        cmonth = "jun_6"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "July_7" Then
        cmonth = "jul_7"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "August_8" Then
        cmonth = "aug_8"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "September_9" Then
        cmonth = "sep_9"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "October_10" Then
        cmonth = "oct_10"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "November_11" Then
        cmonth = "nov_11"
    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "December_12" Then
        cmonth = "dec_12"
    End If

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from " & cyear & " where " & cmonth & "=0", con)
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim myrow As DataRow
    For Each myrow In dt.Rows
        'ListView1.Items.Add(myrow.Item(1))
        'ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(2))
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim listViewItem As New ListViewItem
        listViewItem.SubItems.Add("0")
        listViewItem.SubItems.Add("1")
        listViewItem.SubItems.Add("2")
        For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count
            listViewItem.SubItems(0).Text = i + 1.ToString
        Next
        listViewItem.SubItems(1).Text = myrow.Item(1)
        listViewItem.SubItems(2).Text = myrow.Item(2)
        ListView1.Items.Add(listViewItem)
    Next
```

Comment: Wow.  This is so bad.

Comment: why this so bad  ?? @SamAxe

Comment: i want to know now if you can please @SamAxe

Comment: If you really want to learn, post the code to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: im beginner , so if you can tell me what is my wrong ,this will help me a lot 
tanks @SamAxe

Answer (score 2):

> what i need show the row number in the first column , then show the data from the database in column 2 and 3 .

So, as it turns out, the issue has got nothing whatsoever to do with the row numbers and comes down simply to the fact that you're displaying the actual data in the wrong columns.  You already know how to display data in specific columns because you're already doing it:

```
ListView1.Items.Add(myrow.Item(1))
ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(2))
```

That code is putting data into the first and second columns.  If what you actually want there is a number in the first column and then your data in the second and third then the obvious thing to do is to put a number in the first column and your data in the second and third.  You know how to put text in the first column because you're already doing it, so make that text the number.  You know how to put text in the second column because you're already doing it,  so make that text the appropriate field from your `DataRow`.  If you know how to add text to a second column then you know how to add text to a third column and every subsequent column too.

Alternative syntax:

```
With ListView1.Items.Add(ListView1.Items.Count + 1)
    .SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(2))
End With
```

Comment: If it's not working then you did it wrong.  If we don't know what you did then we don't know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub lstvpop()
    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    Dim item As ListViewItem
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = db.fetchRows("Select * from tbl_class")
    While (reader.Read())
        item = ListView1.Items.Add(ListView1.Items.Count + 1)
        item.Tag = reader(0)
        item.SubItems.Add(reader(1).ToString())
    End While

End Sub
```